# Strange behavior with QTreeView / QFileSystemModel / QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qlineedit, qfilesystemmodel

I have a QTreeView linked to a QFileSystemModel. I also have a QLineEdit with two purposes :

1. when the user click the QTreeView, the QLineEdit is populate with the item clicked (path & filename if applied)
2. when the user edit the QLineEdit and press enter, I want to :

   a. synchronize the QTreeView to that position if the path exist

   b. if the path do not exist, I want to repopulate the QLineEdit with the current position of the QTreeView

Everything is working well except when the condition 2a above is met, I want to :

1. return focus on QTreeView
2. expand the current folder
3. resize the 1st column to contents
4. and scroll the view to that index (scroll to top)

Here is the code I put in place :

```
QDirectorySelector::QDirectorySelector(QString const & title, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    mDirectoryModel = new QFileSystemModel;
    mDirectoryModel->setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    mDirectoryModel->setRootPath("");

    mDirectoryTitle = new QLabel(title);

    mDirectoryView = new QTreeView;
    mDirectoryView->setModel(mDirectoryModel);
    mDirectoryView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    mDirectoryView->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
    mDirectoryView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);

    mDirectoryEdit = new QLineEdit;

    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(mDirectoryTitle);
    layout->addWidget(mDirectoryView);
    layout->addWidget(mDirectoryEdit);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    setLayout(layout);

    connect(mDirectoryView, &QTreeView::clicked, this, &QDirectorySelector::synchronizeEditFromTree);
    connect(mDirectoryEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &QDirectorySelector::synchronizeTreeFromEdit);
    connect(this, &QDirectorySelector::synchronizationDone, this, &QDirectorySelector::reactToExpansionStep1, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(this, &QDirectorySelector::synchronizationStep1Done, this, &QDirectorySelector::reactToExpansionStep2, Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void QDirectorySelector::synchronizeEditFromTree(QModelIndex const & index)
{
    QString directory{ mDirectoryModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath() };
    mDirectoryEdit->setText(directory);
}

void QDirectorySelector::synchronizeTreeFromEdit()
{
    if (QDir(mDirectoryEdit->text()).exists()) {
        mDirectoryView->setFocus();
        mDirectoryView->setCurrentIndex(mDirectoryModel->index(mDirectoryEdit->text()));
        mDirectoryView->setExpanded(mDirectoryView->currentIndex(), true);
        emit synchronizationDone(mDirectoryView->currentIndex());
    } else {
        selectDirectory(mDirectoryView->currentIndex());
    }
}

void QDirectorySelector::reactToExpansionStep1(QModelIndex const & index)
{
    mDirectoryView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
    emit synchronizationStep1Done(mDirectoryView->currentIndex());
}

void QDirectorySelector::reactToExpansionStep2(QModelIndex const & index)
{
    mDirectoryView->scrollTo(mDirectoryView->currentIndex(), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
}
```

If I type an existing path and press enter I got this unexpected behavior :

- the focus is done (ok)
- the current index of the view is done correctly (ok)
- the expension of the sub folder is done (ok)
- the resize of the 1st column is done only at the path level without including the expended part (not expected)
- the scroll to is not done at all (not ok)

At this point, if I return to the QLineEdit and press enter again, everything is done correctly. In fact, I observed this pattern, if the specified folder was never "open" (seen/loaded/expended), I get the unexpected behavior. If the specified was "open" (seen/loaded/expended), I get the expected behavior.

I also try to call two times the code in the finishDirectoryEditing without any success. Everything is the same.

Is anyone have any Idea of what is happening here? And better, any suggestion to solve this unexpected behavior.

I think that the QTreeView working with the QFileSystemModel is already too awkward in term of behavior. I mean, it never hide the expansion mark of an empty folder. May be it's possible to change this but I got no success either with the fetch more strategy I found elsewhere on the net.

Thanks to all!

Comment: I would guess scrolling and resizeing would need the "expand" to have already happened (not just the function call but the GUI operations which happen after you exit the function). I cannot test it now but maybe make a new slot and emit a custom signal at the end. Or better use the `expanded` signal. And in the slot do resize + scroll

Comment: Thanks for this good idea. At first, I tried the `expanded` signal and it didn't work. Then, I tried the custom signal with a standard connection and still didn't work. Then, I added the `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection and it worked partially. I mean, the `resizeColumnToContents` worked but not the `scrollTo` method. Finally, I added a second layer of `emit` and it work partially. The `scrollTo` method scroll the view but not at the top neither at a understandable position. I adjust the code above tho show my last solution.    Do you have other good suggestion?

Comment: sadly not. But I am glad I could help at least a little bit.